# Dynamically Created html elements saved to database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database

I have been teaching myself javascript and now wish to take my program live so I can develop further to learn more and more.

What I am looking to do is store all the rows/cells that are created by the user into a database. So that when they reload the page or someone else loads the page. They can see all the information that other people have added.

Now I feel the best way to do this was to have it sent to the database upon the user clicking a 'save to database' button.

What is the best way to do this, and how would I go about it?

Here is my code:

https://github.com/harryth3hopp3r/JobList

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share data between users you should build a backend for it. Then you can send the data to the backend with an AJAX call, for example.

If you are to build a backend you would need a web server to make it available to your users.

If you want to stick with Javascript you could use NodeJS in your server infrastructure, and then you can connect it to a mongoDB database, which is quite simple to use. I could explain the whole process but I think it's better that you go through the specific tutorials and make more specific questions when they come.

Comment: I had a look into mongoDB, seems pretty complicated. The problem I have is I don't know where to start, or the whole process that is necessary.

I've done a fair bit of research into other peoples post with smilier requests but all the answers seem to be specific to their code. When I try to break that down and change it to fit my I get very confused.

Comment: ok, the simplest solution I could think of is ruby on rails (http://rubyonrails.org/) They have pretty good documentation and guides which can help you. But if you are not experienced with web development don't expect this to be a walk in the park. You would need to invest quite some time

Comment: i have looked into Ruby, Ajax, LocalStorage, pretty much everything.
I can't seem to make any sense of anything. Would you be able to point me in the right direction with local storage. As in show me the first steps to get me on my way.

Comment: localStorage will only help save the data for the current user. The data is not shared between users. If that works for you, it's as simple as call in your javascript something like localStorage.setItem('age', 33) to store a variable (named age in this case) or localStorage.getItem('age') to read this value. You can take a deeper look at it here: http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/